# Scrolling not working in windows phone 8.1

Tags: css

My application works fine on Android and IOS, but I'm facing the scrolling issue on Windows Phone 8.1. I have done some research and tried to modify my css with:

```css
body {
    -ms-content-zooming: none;
}
```

and also by adding the following:

```css
body.platform-windowsphone .scroll-content,
body.platform-windowsphone8 .scroll-content {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

but none of them work.

Comment: add the css tag instead of the javascript one.

Comment: i already did but not working

Comment: Of course, it will be not working, when you change tags here :D